# HTML handling in Windows 8 Runtime / Store App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, html-parsing, windows-store-apps

I've got a `string` containing HTML, and I need to parse it within Windows 8 Store App. *[System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.aspx)* is not available for store apps. I just need to extract some page links, image links and some text content.

I suppose I could use regexps for a quick&dirty solution, but there must be a better way. Parsing should be robust and not reject the whole string even if HTML is slightly broken or nonstandard. Googling provides some alternatives, but I find the results inconclusive, and would like a straight answer (or list of answers) from someone who has actually done this. Some code would be nice, or just a link to SO answer with good code.

Some code for clarification:

```
public async void doSomeHtmlStuff(string url) {
    System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string html = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

    // parse the html, how? 

    // NOT anything like this, document tree is needed for context
    var links = Regex.Matches(html, "<a\\s*href=.*>.*</a>");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it will increase the overhead of your application, I'd suggest you actually load the HTML into the `WebView` if possible and use DOM access via the `InvokeScript` ([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh738508)) method to gain access to the DOM and do whatever searching is necessary. The HTML parser of IE is tolerant and can handle nearly any HTML you throw at it.

You could use `NavigateToString` ([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetostring.aspx)) to load the HTML if needed.

The reason I'm suggesting this technique is that given that HTML5 isn't required to be well-formed (like XHTML), you'll likely encounter a variety of odd situations that will make reliably parsing of the DOM quite challenging, especially if you need the structure of the DOM to be retained as part of the search.

I've (or a team I've been on have) used a few DOM parsing libraries in the past for C# and found them all to be lacking in robustness. If you have a very fixed set of HTML you're parsing, you might find one of them helpful.

It wasn't until very recently that Google announced the release of their Gumbo library, a pure HTML 5 parser, written in C (which of course won't help you).

Comment: I ended up using HtmlAgilityPack, and did not try this approach, but it sounds like a good way to go too, so I'm accepting this.

Comment: Good luck with the HtmlAgilityPack ... we abandoned it as well as it's not as tolerant as browsers with messy HTML and wasn't super efficient memory-wise from what I recall.